How to make this soft drink material?
I have been making a Fanta bottle model. I was working at the material of the soda, and the reference picture and what I made don't look similar:

And here is the shader I used for the soda:


Please provide more details, such as what exactly you don't like about your shader.

The Fanta on the left is a pack-shot, strongly back-lit, and not refracting any dark regions of its environment. And.. real-life light can bounce infinitely many times around the material without terminating in black. If you share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ , we can try ways of addressing those differences.

Yes it looks more like a problem of lighting than material
